# Understanding DASH and mpd files – where is a list of m4s files?

Tags: video, streaming, mpeg-dash

I am using website https://bitmovin.com/demos/drm to test and learn.

The site requests `11331.mpd` file and gets back information about 5 different resolution video streams and 1 audio. All with the same `KID` `eb676abb-cb34-5e96-bbcf-616630f1a3da`. It then proceeds requesting `init.mp4` file and follows with requests `segment_0.m4s` where `0` gets increased by `1` for each of the following requests.

Here is my first question: Where in the `mpd` file do I see how many segments are available? Is that information even included or it stops only when server stops responding with proper replies?

If I understand this correctly, I should be able to concatenate initialization `mp4` file and all of the segments into a `mp4` file, which would then also need to be decrypted. For example with `ffmpeg`.

Passing the path to `11331.mpd` to `youtube-dl` does not work on this page, although I am sure this did work for me in the past on other sites. `mpd` xml file also seem to be way more obfuscated than the `m3u8` files.

For example: how does one parse the information like this:
`<cenc:pssh xmlns:cenc="urn:mpeg:cenc:2013">AAAAW3Bzc2gAAAAA7e+LqXnWSs6jyCfc1R0h7QAAADsIARIQ62dqu8s0Xpa7z2FmMPGj2hoNd2lkZXZpbmVfdGVzdCIQZmtqM2xqYVNkZmFsa3IzaioCSEQyAA==</cenc:pssh>`

It looks like `base64` encoded but trying to decode it does not return readable data (parts of it are readable). Which could mean part of the data returned does not have readable ascii representation. In that case, how to properly cut this up `AAAAW3Bzc2gAAAAA7e+LqXnWSs6jyCfc1R0h7QAAADsIARIQ62dqu8s0Xpa7z2FmMPGj2hoNd2lkZXZpbmVfdGVzdCIQZmtqM2xqYVNkZmFsa3IzaioCSEQyAA==` to extract the readable data, and what data is hidden (binary) in unreadable places?